# DeckGL mouse info coordinates display wrong

Tags: coordinates, mapbox, layer, deck.gl

I display coordinates hovered by the mouse position in a pathLayer, the map is in a mercator projection, the coordinate display wrong, it looks as though, there is an offset, It looks as though the longitude value is way off, and  the zoom of the map affects the  display as well. I have double checked the lat, long, coordinateSystem is latlong, tried rounding the values, none of this result in the expected path.
Is there a projection or coordinate transformation i should do?

````
      data:[{coors: DrawPositions}], 
      getPath: d => d.coors,
      positionFormat: `XY`,
      getColor: [250, 250, 0, 255],
      getWidth: 20,
      widthMinPixels: 20
    })```

 
   [coordinates i get][1]
   [the white line is the mouse path, the yellow is the coordinates
][2]
[probs more of a longitude issue][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fhzp.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huwP2.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y27ry.png
````